# How to test the ads displayed on UI, using Selenium WebDriver/RC

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-rc, selenium-ide

How to test the ads which displayed on web page. This ads are injected thorugh some plugins. When I record using IDE, it displays the adds on Firefox browser. But when I run the webdriver selenium script from eclips, it does not show any ads, on the webpage of browser launched by selenium..

How to rectify this issue?

Comment: Well to get to the bottom of it, you are going to have to find out exactly how those adverts are created. This means, if you have access the source code, look at it and work it out and/or work with your developers. Once you know the exact process the website is taking to make these adverts in the first place, it's going to help in diagnosing why it doesn't show up when using Selenium.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, Selenium uses a Firefox profile which is separate from your normal profile when you open the browser manually. So, plugins you've added using your normal profile will not be available to Selenium by default.

So, if ads are injected into a page by a plugin you've installed, that would explain why you aren't seeing them without the plugin when you open FF with Selenium.

You can create a profile to use with Selenium by following these steps:

1. Make sure all your firefox instance are closed
2. Click Start>Run
3. Type `firefox.exe -ProfileManager -no-remote`
4. Select “Create Profile”
5. Click “Next”
6. Enter new profile name
7. Select a directory folder to store your new profile
8. Click “Finish”
9. Select “Don’t ask at startup”
10. Click “Start Firefox” and configure your settings
11. Set Profile back to “default” (to use your normal profile outside Selenium)

And then in Java, set up your driver to use that profile - for example, if you create a profile called "SELENIUM", your java might look like this:

```
ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();
FirefoxProfile ffprofile = profile.getProfile("SELENIUM");
driver = new FirefoxDriver(ffprofile);
```

Comment: Thanks Pat, it worked.. I didnt created a new profile, instead i used the default profile in Java program.

Answer (score 2):

Testing experience from me: I work for German company, placed in Czech Republic. And there is the page which targets Czech audience. So the AdWords are made for Czech people.

But the company firewall is placed in Germany, which means, that the page thinks I sit in Germany, although I sit in Prague. Which also means that no ads are being displayed to me.

Long story short: Make sure you do not have some another issue like this when running selenium and when running from your browser...

Comment: Pavel, i dont have any such firewall settings. When i manually browse to that URL, i see the adds displayed properly. It does not show the ads, only in the browser which is launched by Selenium RC

Comment: I know, but maybe. Just *maybe* - the browser tells the page different data then by browsing manually. I did not check that, but might be plausible explanation of what is happening to you...